# Getenv() error when invoked more than one time

Tags: c, getenv

I have codes to get environment variable name from stand input and call library function `getenv()` to get the value and output.

Here are codes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXLEN 256

int main(void)

{
    char *envName;
    char *envValue;
    char *envEntry;
    char *envVar=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAXLEN);

    while(NULL!=(envName=gets(envVar))){

    envValue=getenv(envName);
    if(envValue){
        printf("%s\n",envValue);

        envEntry=strtok(envValue,";");

        while(envEntry){
            printf("%s\n",envEntry);

            envEntry=strtok(NULL,";");
        }
    }else{
        printf("not found\n");
    }
}

    return 0;
}
```

If the environment variable `"path"` contains `"a;b;c;d"`.
While it runs,if type a string "path" first time,it works well,but if type "path" again it only gets the first string like`"a"` or `"a;b"`.

Comment: *Never* use gets.  It is utterly deprecated.  Use `fgets` instead.  Search the web for numerous reasons why.

Comment: Do you know how strtok works?

Comment: @immibis strtok() will keep a pointer to the first parameter after first invoke and will use this pointer if the first parameter is NULL if invoked again

Comment: @chaox That's part of how it works, but not the relevant part. What does its return value point to?

Comment: @immibis the delimiter will replaced by null in return value

Comment: @immibis but why it works well first time if I type "path"

Comment: @chaox The return value is a pointer, therefore it doesn't contain the delimiter, or a null character, or indeed any characters, because it only contains an address. However, what does it point to?

Comment: @immibis it points to the address of first character that delimiters does not contain in source string

Answer (score 4):

You're not allowed to modify the string that `getenv()` returns. `strtok()` replaces the delimiter characters with null characters, so you're violating this restriction. Typical implementations of `getenv()` work by returning a pointer directly into the environment string, so you're affecting how it searches the environment in future calls. Originally, your environment contained

```
path=a;b;c;d\0
```

When you called `strtok()`, it replaced all the semicolons with null bytes:

```
path=a\0b\0c\0d\0
```

So when you call `getenv("path")` the next time, it returns a pointer to this, and the first `\0` terminates the environment variable.

You should make a copy of `evnValue` and use `strtok()` on this.

Comment: Yes,you are right.I make a copy of  `envValue` and it works.But why it does not give the correct value when I type "path" again.Does it cache the string which envVal points to and return the address of string cached when `getenv()` invoked again?

Comment: When you used `strtok`, you modified the environment.

Comment: I've added a detailed explanation of why this happens.